# Swift 2 TableView passing image to next controller from network

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview

My tableView show a list of image from network. I have tried to pass the image data to next controller, but i am fail.
This is my steps:

1) declare an empty UIImage variable =>  2)set the image of cells from url => 3) get the image of the cell when the user selecting a cell => pass it to next Controller

However, it is passing a empty image to the next controller..

```
var myImage: UIImage?

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! customCell

                if let cellImage = URLArray[indexPath.row]["image"] {
                        do {
                            let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: cellImage!)!
                            let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)

                            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
                            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
                                (data, response, error) -> Void in

                                if (error == nil && data != nil) {
                                    func display_image() {
                                        cell.placeImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)!
                                    }
                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image)
                                } else {
                                    cell.placeImage.image = UIImage(named: "image1")!
                                }
                            }
                            task.resume()
                        }
            }
            return cell
        }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! customCell
            self.myImage = selectedCell.placeImage.image

            performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
    }

// prepareForSegue
   if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
  let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! secondViewController)
   controller.Image = self.myImage
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the reference of the tapped cell in your prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier{
            if(identifier == "showDetail") {
                if let sender = sender as? customCell{
                        if let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? secondViewController {
                                secondViewController.Image = sender.placeImage
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To get this properly work you need to set your "showDetail" segue in the storyboard from the **Cell** to the secondViewController

Comment: i have already set the identifier of the segue. And it is not working... i have no idea how to fix this problem.

Comment: Try to delete the "performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)", maybe it's in conflict with the storyboard